# Umbraco Form data lost if validation fails

Tags: umbraco7

I just added a new Umbraco Form using the new Umbraco Forms in Umbraco 7.2.1.

When I fill in my form with errors, the validation message(s) will show up. 
On this moment, the data I added is lost.

Is there a way to keep the form data? Because my form has too many fields to let the user fill in the data again.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: My umbraco website is on hold for other reasons. So I didn't have time to search a solution for this. 
I still have this issue.